# Интеграция c++ (или c) в python

Tags: python, c++, c

Вот есть библиотека `ctypes` которая позволяет использовать `dll`, `so` и т.д.

Но хотелось бы что бы можно было запускать все это дело без динамических библиотек (напрямую)

типо

**lib.cpp:**

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void print(string text) {
    cout << text;
}
```

**main.py:**

```py
import либа_для_спп
load = либа_для_спп.load_file("lib.cpp")
load.print("hello")
```

Comment: Ну что ж, можно и так... но придется тянуть с питоном еще и компилятор С++...

Comment: Как именно "можно так"?

Comment: Написать питоновскую функцию, которая будет разбирать С++'ный файл, выдирать из него необходимое, компилировать и запускать. Небольшая работа для большого коллектива...

Comment: если так сделать то каждый запуск программы придётся заново компилировать код, что не очень хорошо

Comment: Вам нужно смотреть в сторону Cython.